# Header File Clarification

Tags: c++, file, header

I'm making a black jack game. Because of that I need a Card Header and Deck Header.

Problem is, I don't quite understand how to use headers. I know you are supposed to put for example `isFaceUp();` inside there, but how do I make, for example `flip();` to change `isFaceUp();` from False to True?

Comment: It looks like you need to read up some basics on coding in C++. I recommend that you read some tutorials online or get a book, then come back here if you have specific problems

Comment: Well, I'm on my second year of C++ course. My school doesn't teach that much and I've read 3 or 4 websites which gave me a simple idea of how to use Header files but still...

Comment: The header files provides [declarations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declaration_(computer_programming)) of functions, which are defined in the .cpp file

Comment: Yes that I know. But how do I make the flip(); function change the value in isFaceUp;

Comment: That depends on your implementation of the class. You'd need to post some code here for us to help. Have a quick read of the [guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask questions here so we can best help you.

Answer (score 4):

while in header files there are function declarations their definition should be placed in corresponding .cpp files

for instance:
//cards.h :

```
class Cards
{
  public:
   Cards();
   void flip();
   bool isFaceUp();
 private:
   bool isflipped;
}
```

//cards.cpp :

```
Cards::Cards()
{
 //code here
}
void Cards::flip()
{
 isflipped=!isFlipped;
}
bool Cards::isFaceUp()
{
 return isflipped;
}
```